# iPad stuck with "iCloud Backup" message -- can't use it!

Tags: ios, ipad, backup, performance

Yesterday I opened my iPad to discover a weird message I'd never seen before on my screen, that I cannot get rid of:

[image]

It prevents me from interacting with anything else on the screen!

So I plugged it in, made sure it had a good WiFi signal, and left it to charge overnight. Unfortunately this morning, the same message was still there. And I still couldn't get rid of it.

Next I tried connecting it to iTunes and as you can see, despite the message I can't get rid of, my attempt at backing it up DID work!

[image]

Unfortunately I still have this message I cannot get rid of! I've tried "Backup Now", and it appears to function correctly, but the message is still there!

I can interact with the "OK" button on the message, but nothing else. I press it and (aside from changing colour) it does nothing. The message stays where it is. The buttons on the iPad's body still have all the same functionality as before... but I cannot interact with anything on the screen. My iPad is essentially useless!

What do I do?

Answer (score 2):

Ah!!! Resetting the iPad by holding down the button on the top and on the front did.

[image]

Phew!

Comment: Thank you for documenting this. Re-starting the device can fix an amazing number of things.

Comment: @bassplayer7 I certainly won't forget about it in the future! :)